# Как соединиться с DB2 через OLEDB? Нет провайдера IBMDADB2

Tags: c#, oledb, db2

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД IBM DB2 z/OS ver12, но VS говорит, что IBMDADB2 не зарегистрирован. 
Строка подключения выглядит так:

```
Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=urDataBase;Hostname=urServerAddress;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;
Uid=urUsername;Pwd=urPassword;
```

Я не вижу возможности подключитсья к DB2 даже через мастер подключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какую либу используете? как выглядид в коде подключение и дальнейшее использование?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц  using System.Data.OleDb;
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
//execute queries
myConnection.Close();

Comment: DB2 на борту имеет ODBC, создайте в ODBC (odbccab) алиас, и делайте коннект через ODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно было установить драйвер вот с этой страницы https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers

Обратите внимание, что тут версия 11.5, если у вас другой сервер, то нужна другая версия драйвера. В противном случае будет выходить ошибка лицензирования.